# Ubuntu +Apache doesn't work on port 80

Tags: port

I have some problems with apache (OS Ubuntu). for some reasons apache doesn't work on port 80.

For this settings:
etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

etc/apache2/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

[netstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuiXE.jpg).
I try to connect "my_server_ip" or "my_server_ip:80" browser say "connection closed"

If i change  port to 8080(for example)  try to connect "my_server_ip:8080" it's work fine and i see default apache page.

settings:
etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

etc/apache2/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    </VirtualHost>
```

[netstats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oicx7.jpg).